# Document object is undefined in a react form

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs

i have a pure javascript form which is auto submitted with this function:

```
<script language="Javascript" > 
function OnLoadEvent(){ 
document.threedfrom.submit(); 
}
</script>
</head> 
<body OnLoad="OnLoadEvent();" > 
<form name="threedfrom" action="https://a12232.com" method="POST">
```

As a result the form is submitting when the page is loaded. I'm trying to apply the same functionality in a react class. Part of my component is here:

```
handleSubmit() {
    ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.threedfrom).submit();
  }
  render() {
    }
    return (
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} ref="threedfrom" name="threedfrom" action={this.props.acsUrl} method="POST">
          <textarea style={{ display: 'none' }} name="PaReq"
```

but it is not seem to work because my form is not submitting load page. Any ideas? I've also add this

```
componentDidMount() {
    ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.threedfrom).submit();
  }
```

but no results

Comment: are you trying to submit the form once it is rendered? What version of React are you using?

Comment: Yes i'm trying exactly this!! my react version  "react": "^15.4.1",

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} ref="threedfrom"`  to `<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} ref={(c) => this.threedfrom = c}` and for the mounting part:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.threedfrom!==null this.threedfrom.submit();
}
```